# python3 os.popen() windows explorer with focus on specific directory

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, windows-explorer

I have some code that will open Windows Explorer for the user, but it always opens with the focus on 'my documents' which I understand is the Windows Explorer default.

I can step it back one level to the current username directory, but I cannot force it to open at a network drive>folder defined by a variable. I've tried adding focus using the OS vb script (had to try something and it looked very similar in syntax?) but this still ignores the folder path and resorts to the user directory:

```
def Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Dir():
    import subprocess
    fldr2opn = currentproject.get()
    # os.popen('start explorer,"%s" ' % fldr2opn)
    os.popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n, /select, "%s"' % fldr2opn)
```

if I put in a `print(fldr2opn)` statement before the `os.popen()`  it returns the correct path in this case `"P:\Projects_2013\test_dir"` so I know that is correct, it's just the `os.popen` syntax that has me stumped.

Answer (score 1):

For people who still need an answer, I managed to actually open a specific directory this way :

```
    # For an absolute path or relative from My Documents
    import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n /cwd="' + directory + '"')
    p.wait()

    # For a relative path from the current directory
    import subprocess
    import os
    p = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n /cwd="' +
                         os.getcwd() + os.sep + directory + '"')
    p.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the space between the options:

```
os.popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE /n,/select,%s' % fldr2opn)
```

To make this work with spaces in the path to open, U suggest to use `subprocess.Popen()` with

```
cmd = ['c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE', '/n,/select,%s' % fldr2opn]
```

Related: [Windows Explorer command line options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457)

Comment: so close.. i have changed the line to ' subprocess.Popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE /cwd="C:\Temp"')' and this works, it will open explorer focused on teh C:\Temp directory but when i try to substitute in the string using  'subprocess.Popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE /cwd="%s"' %fldr2opn)' it only opens the my documents folder, i have tried every way i can think of with this syntax but it doesn't like it for and i cant see why, i dont get an error because explorer opens

Comment: Try `subprocess.Popen('c:\windows\EXPLORER.EXE', cwd=fldr2opn)`

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work either, it opens explorer at the 'library' folder ? its quite bizarre.

Comment: I have now found the man page for explorer. See my edits for a solution.

Comment: i read the page for explorer and managed to open explorer at the /currentuser/my documents(explorer default) the part of code after 'explorer' is apparently ignored ? 'def Open_Win_Explorer_and_Select_Dir():
    import subprocess
    fldrname = os.path.basename(currentproject.get())
    print(fldrname)
    #subprocess.Popen('c:\\windows\\EXPLORER.EXE'cwd=('P:\\Projects_2013\\')fldrname)
    subprocess.Popen('explorer /select,//WRDBSVR/Project_Data/Projects_2013/'+fldrname)

Comment: I think you still need the `/n`. And you need to use backslashes for the file path because Explorer might not support forward slashes from the command line (many versions don't support it from the UI, either).